# How to move an object from start position to end position on mouse over and then back again on mouse out

Tags: javascript, animation, positioning

I have been having problems moving a div box from a to b and then back again. I also need it to return back to start pos when the mouse goes out of the div box. This is what ive come up with so far.

```
<div id="tank" style=" width:344px; height:300px;
 background-image:url('images/warning2.png');
 box-shadow:0px 0px 100px;
 ;border-radius:20px; position:relative; left:-180px; top:10px;">
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">

 document.getElementById('tank').onmouseover = function() {
 var elem = this, 
 pos = -180,

 timer = setInterval(function() {
 pos--;
 elem.style.left = pos+"px";
 if( pos == 500) clearInterval(timer) ;
 document.getElementById('plane').onmouseover = null;
 },1);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `jQuery`, you can do something like this:

```
$("#tank").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '-=180'
    });
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '+=180'
    });
  }
);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/QgF2h/

Answer (score 0):

Your position starts at -180 and your final position is +500. But you're decreasing the value of the position variable so it will never hit 500.

As for going back on mouse out, you should do something like this:

```
var timer = null;
var tank = document.getElementById('tank');

function animate(elem, target)
{
    var pos = parseInt(elem.style.left.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g, ""));

    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function()
    {
        elem.style.left = (pos += pos < target ? 1 : -1) + "px";
        if(pos == target) clearInterval(timer) ;
    }, 1);
}

tank.addEventListener("mouseover", function()
{
    animate(this, 500);
}, false);

tank.addEventListener("mouseout", function()
{
    animate(this, -180);
}, false);
```

​

Comment: If you're going to use JQ, might as well just make it all in JQ.

Comment: Where did anyone mention jQuery?